# Mercado pago: agregar dinamicamente mas de un producto

Tags: php, array, checkout

tengo el problema de que no puedo generar dinamicamente items para agregar a un pago de mercado pago con la api de PHP

esto funciona me funciona bien para un solo producto:

```
// Crea un objeto de preferencia
$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();
$preference->back_urls = array(
    "success" => "?estado=1",
    "failure" => "?estado=0",
    "pending" => "?estado=2"
);

$preference->payment_methods = array(
    "excluded_payment_types" => array(
    array("id" => "ticket")
  ),
  "installments" => 12
);

$preference->external_reference = $_SESSION["IdUsuario"];
$preference->auto_return = "approved";
$preference->binary_mode = true; 

// Crea un ítem en la preferencia
$item = new MercadoPago\Item();
$item->title = 'Carga de Creditos';
$item->quantity = 1;
$item->unit_price = $_SESSION["MercadoPago"];


$preference->items = array($item);
$preference->save();
```

cuando intento generar un nuevo item en un bucle foreach en apariencia lo hace pero cuando intento salvar los items genera un error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\unicasport\core\controller
    \mp\vendor\mercadopago\dx-php\src\MercadoPago\Generic\RecuperableError.php on line 27
```

esto este codigo es el que genera el error:

```
// Crea un array de ítems en la preferencia
        foreach ($data['carrito'] as $producto) {
        $item= new MercadoPago\Item();
        $items[]=$item->id = $producto['id'];
        $items[]=$item->title = $producto['nombre'];
        $items[]=$item->quantity = $producto['cantidad'];
        $items[]=$item->unit_price = $producto['precio'];
        $items[]=$item->currency_id = "ARS";

    }



    // Crea un objeto de preferencia
    $preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();
    $preference->back_urls = array(
        "success" => "?estado=1",
        "failure" => "?estado=0",
        "pending" => "?estado=2"
    );

    $preference->payment_methods = array(
        "excluded_payment_types" => array(
        array("id" => "ticket")
      ),
      "installments" => 12
    );

    $preference->external_reference = gethostname();
    $preference->auto_return = "approved";
    $preference->binary_mode = true; 

    $preference->items = array($items);
    $preference->save();
```

contenido de array:

```
 array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 81,
    'imagen' => 'assets/img/654202-MLA31114161961_062019-O.jpg',
    'nombre' => 'Soga De Salto',
    'color' => 'Azul',
    'categoria' => 'Boxeo',
    'stock' => 4,
    'descripcion' => 'SOGAS PARA SALTAR DE CABLE ,CON PUÑO EN PVC!!',
    'activa' => 1,
    'precio' => 180,
    '$$hashKey' => 'object:4',
    'subtotal' => 360,
    'cantidad' => 2,
      ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 82,
    'imagen' => 'assets/img/784920-MLA31041980182_062019-O.jpg',
    'nombre' => 'Step De Pvc De 13 Cm.',
    'color' => 'Azul',
    'categoria' => 'Boxeo',
    'stock' => 2,
    'descripcion' => 'Step de pvc,funcional, ideal para ejercicios de piernas, soporta mas ',
    'activa' => 1,
    'precio' => 494,
    '$$hashKey' => 'object:5',
    'subtotal' => 988,
    'cantidad' => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 83,
    'imagen' => 'assets/img/863509-MLA31655154449_082019-O.jpg',
    'nombre' => 'Pelotas De Handball N°3, Cuero Legitimo!!',
    'color' => 'Rojo',
    'categoria' => 'Futbol',
    'stock' => 3,
    'descripcion' => 'Pelotas de handball n°3, de cuero legitimo, peso y medida ............',
    'activa' => 1,
    'precio' => 890,
    '$$hashKey' => 'object:6',
    'subtotal' => 2670,
    'cantidad' => 3,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => 84,
    'imagen' => 'assets/img/650521-MLA31621924539_072019-O.jpg',
    'nombre' => 'Bolso Porta Pelotas Y Materiales,en Cordura Vinili',
    'color' => 'Azul',
    'categoria' => 'Futbol',
    'stock' => 7,
    'descripcion' => 'Bolso porta pelotas o porta materiales, fabricado en..........',
    'activa' => 1,
    'precio' => 653.02,
    '$$hashKey' => 'object:7',
    'subtotal' => 2612.08,
    'cantidad' => 4,
  ),
)
```

Donde esta el error?

Answer (score 2):

yo me mareé.

despues de un paseo y una gaseosa me di cuenta del error.

encontre esta solucion:

```
    $items= array();
    // Crea un array de ítems en la preferencia
    foreach ($data['carrito'] as $producto) 
    {
      $items[]= array
        (
        "title"         =>  $producto['nombre'],
        "quantity"      =>  $producto['cantidad'],
        "currency_id"   =>  "ARS",
        "unit_price"        =>  intval($producto['precio']),
        "id"                =>  $producto['id'],
       )
    }
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.